# ios check if a UITextfield.text has a numeric value greater than 52

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, numeric, maxlength

I am busy trying to figure out how to detect if a UITextfield text has a numeric value greater than 52?

I tried using `NSScanner` with no luck.

```
NSScanner * scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:self.repeatOccurrenceFrequencyWeeklyTF.text];
    double val;
    [scanner scanDouble:&val];
    // Scanned the whole string and ended up with a positive value
    if( [scanner isAtEnd] && val > 52 ){
        NSLog(@"'%@'? I accept.", self.repeatOccurrenceFrequencyWeeklyTF.text);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"'%@' is no good.", self.repeatOccurrenceFrequencyWeeklyTF.text);
        [self showMessage:@"Week Error" Message:@"The week field must be filled in."];
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just convert your `texField` in an `int` value like this :
`int changeid = [idchoice.text intValue];`
And after compare this `int` value to 52